# How expensive is on-the-fly zipping?

Tags: tomcat, zip

I have a repository of files on server that have to be downloaded to mobile devices. The files on the server can be updated on the server after they have been downloaded to the devices; and on a subsequent connection only the modified files have to be downloaded to the device.

My choices are to either prepare the zips in advance or to prepare them on the fly. For creating them in advance, I have to create a zip in advance for all previous versions of the repository. To prepare it on the fly, I can find out which files need to be downloaded and zip them on the fly.

I think the decision depends on how expensive it would be to prepare such a zip on the fly.

My questions are:

- How expensive is it to create a zip on the fly? There can be potentially thousands of mobile devices; it should be possible to cache a prepared zip file but I want to also consider the cost of zipping separately for each connection. The purpose behind this is to avoid storing historical data on the server
- Are there any other parameters I should consider besides the cost of on-the-fly zipping?

The server is running in an embedded tomcat process.

Comment: In this scenario, it is typically preferable to zip files as the users request them but to save a copy for a while. That way you can serve up the saved copies to users requesting the same files around the same time. (But if the files are unique to a particular user you might want to zip preemptively if your server gets overloaded when many users download at the same time.)

Comment: Thanks @LeeMeador. The fileset is not unique to a user and do hope to be able to save (cache) a prepared zip file.

Answer (score 1):

On-the-fly compression during network operations (as used in SSH/SFTP, SSL/TLS, HTTP(S) and more) not only not decreases transfer speed, but can significantly increase it! So compression is welcome whenever possible.

Now, you can compress the data sent to the channel or you can compress the file and send the compressed file. The problem with sending compressed ZIP is that in most cases (streaming ZIP compression libraries are rare, but IIRC they do exist) you can't stream a ZIP file while it's being packed -- you need to wait for completion of packing before responding to the request. This can create problems if archives are huge (dozens of megabytes or larger). The benefit is that you can pack the file once and keep it in the cache for some long time (say a week or a month).

Comment: I don't really need online (streaming) zip; I am trying to decide between zipping as needed (including using a cached copy) v/s storing historical data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the slide #13 in [this presentation from Google](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//people/jeff/stanford-295-talk.pdf).

They use [zippy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) which is somewhat customized zip implementation, but the point is clear: zipping is far cheaper than sending data across. Yes, you still have to send the file across, therefore the savings for small files are smaller, but most of the time zipping pays off.

Comment: I am already aware of the benefits of compressing. The question is whether to pre-prepare them on server (store historical state) v/s create them on-the-fly (with possible caching)

Comment: It is really hard to answer your question without knowing your data and budget. Generally the pre-processing (preparing zips in your case) is the way to go, but if your storage is somehow expensive then probably you need to see how much are you prepared to pay for lower latency.

Comment: storage is cheap, the cost is in adding state information on server. if i want to pre-create the zip i need one for the delta from each previous version to the latest; to create them on the fly i only need the current snapshot on the server

Comment: In this case (sorry, I misunderstood your question initially) I completely agree with Lee Meador's comment. This seems the best strategy to go to me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand Lee's approach, I am trying to decide between zipping on the fly vs pre-preparing the zip and seems to suggest do to both :)